# Input validation checking if the input is a double

Tags: java, validation, input, try-catch

I want to check if the input I entered is the correct data type. For example if the user enters an `int` when I want them to enter a `double` then the program tells them there is an error. This is what I have so far:

```
System.out.println("Enter the temperature in double:");
String temp = input.nextLine();
try
{
    Double temperature = Double.parseDouble(temp);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    isValid = false;
    System.out.println("Temperature  must be a double ");
}
```

All its doing is continuing on through the program and not printing out the error message when I enter an `int`. Been stuck on this for a while so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Every `int` is a valid `double`, so why would you expect it to fail?

Comment: An `int` is also a `double`! You have to explicitely test against _intness_, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to validate only decimal numbers (not including integers). If that is the case then you can use a *regex* for the same :

```
System.out.println("Enter the temperature in double:");
String temp = input.nextLine();
while (temp != null && !temp.matches("^[0-9]*\\.([0-9]+)+$")) {       // use of regex here
    System.out.println("Enter the temperature in double:");
    temp = input.nextLine();                                          // read input again
}
```

This will loop until the user gives in only a valid decimal input. Explanation of [this](https://regex101.com/r/EMErMR/1) *regex*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want `int` to get accepted, you can just add an `if` to check whether the input `String` has a decimal point or not.

```
    System.out.println("Enter the temperature in double:");
    String temp = (new Scanner(System.in)).next();
    if (temp.contains(".")) {
        try {
            Double temperature = Double.parseDouble(temp);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            isValid = false;
            System.out.println("Temperature  must be a double ");
        }
    } else {
        isValid = false;
        System.out.println("Temperature  must be a double ");
    }
```

Comment: Just retaining the original try catch should deal with that problem, edited!